# CSS 100% width on browser resize

Tags: css, width, scrollbars

Hi all I'm trying to build a layout using CSS and I'm coming up against a strange problem. Well strange for me. I have 3 divs a **Header**, a **Footer** and a **MainContent** area. Header and Footer must remain at a constant width of 100% while the MainContent area must be fixed centrally at 996px; This is all fine however when I resize the browser window to a width lower than 996px and then scroll the content of the window right the 100% header and footer seem to be truncated and are no longer 100%. I've knocked up a little bare-bones script to illustrate the issue (styles inline to keep it compact). I know I can add overflow:hidden to each of the containers in order to turn off the scrollbars when to window is resized. I've also written a small piece of jQuery to force the div's back to 
the width, if the width drops below a certain width. However my question is around the CSS, is there a better pure CSS fix for this issue? Or can anybody explain why this happens?
Thankyou in advance!
DotsC

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>div width test</title>
</head>
<body style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%">

    <div id="header-content" style="width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#0000ff; height:50px"></div>

    <div id="main-content" style="width:996px; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#ff00ff; height:250px; margin:auto">
        <div id="inner-content">
            CONTENT OF THE PAGE HERE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-content" style="width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#00ffff; height:70px"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely clear on your issue, but you can set `min-width:996px;` on the header and footer to keep them at least as wide as the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and please use HTML5's doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body{margin:0;text-align:center;}
            .header,.content,.footer{text-align:left;clear:both;margin:0 auto;}
            .header,.footer{width:100%;background-color:blue;height:128px;min-width:996px;}
            .content{width:996px;height:512px;background-color:red;}
        </style>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            Header stuff here
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Page content stuff here
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            and your footer...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI - This solution worked for what I was looking for In IE8 / IE7.  Adding to .header and .footer {width:100%; min-width:970px}.  Thank you +1