# Resizing Browser + Horizontal Scrolling = Div Display Hidden

Tags: html, browser, horizontal-scrolling

When You Size the Browser Down to under 1,000 Pixels in WIDTH and THEN scroll horizontally to the right, all the containing divs keep the same width of the browser window and do not extend to the full width.

My width is 100% for the Footer and Body.

Below is an example of what I am talking about across all browsers I have tested, So I am assuming 1 Solution will fix them all

Opera 12.0
Firefox 11.0
Chrome 20.0.1132.47
Safari 5.1.1
IE 9.08

Working Sample Here : http://glustik.com/siteTemplate2012/

[image]

Any advice from an expert would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your Time.

Answer (score 0):

As per the solution in other questions on stackoverflow: adding a min-width attribute to the divs should do the trick.

In your case I think:

```
min-width: 1024px;
```

(width: 100% only means 100% of viewport)

see also:

[100% width bg images not extending on horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042979/100-width-bg-images-not-extending-on-horizontal-scroll)

and

[CSS 100% width on browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805150/css-100-width-on-browser-resize)