# css: width of html and body tags set to 100% - why this is needed?

Tags: html, css, properties, width

I'm curious what is the purpose of `html, body{width:100%}` in the css file? Is it kind of css reset code?

Disabling this piece of code doesn't affect on what I see in the browser. Is it a "bugfix" for some old browser or for mobile devices? Am I missing something?
Could anybody please explain?

Thank  you.

Comment: It's not necessary in most cases.

Comment: In most cases? What are the cases when it is really needed? Thank you.

Comment: if you just had that without removing the initial natural padding of the body, you would end up with scroll bars.   The only use I see for it is if you wanted overflow hidden so you didn't get scrollbars if your viewport was smaller than the width of the items within

Comment: Compare http://jsfiddle.net/yLTTY/ with http://jsfiddle.net/yLTTY/1/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, width:100% is used when you want a block-level element to fill any remaining space inside it's parent or when an element is inheriting a set width value that you want to override. But in most cases it is unnecessary or will bring undesirable results.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know it's not necessary maximum time, some time not mentioning this is creates problem with IE browser by improper formatting of the content. otherwise there is no need.

Comment: What IE version? Any example or links that describes this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Haradzieniec, not exactly.. I've faced this issue one time but now not able to recall that. sorry for that. please go thorough this link if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805150/css-100-width-on-browser-resize

Answer (score 0):

Understand it this way.

**HTML is parent of BODY.

BODY is parent of the content.**
Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property, so the HTML element needs to have it's height set.And since the content of body will probably need to change dynamically. Setting min-height of the body to 100% makes that happen.

If we are using **overflow:hidden** with body and the body isn't able to take the height of dynamic content then the part outside the body height won't be visible .

Now the question is
**When doesn't the body take the height of the dynamic content ?**

When we are using floating elements .The height of the floating elements are not calculated by the parent until we use **overflow:auto**.

Comment: Question is about width, not height.